# How to get the path of a file in Tcl?

Tags: file, search, command, tcl, glob

File name is known. I need to get the path of that file by searching a directory recursively through Tcl commands.

Ex: `file.txt` is in `subdirectory1` in `directory`. I need the output to be `directory/subdirectory1/file.txt`

```
set proj [glob -type d *]
set sol [glob -directory $proj -type d *]
#puts "$sol"
```

I have tried this assuming only one directory will be present. Realized there can be more subdirectories present.

Answer (score 1):

A few ways that save having to write directory tree traversal code yourself:

With the [TclX package](https://github.com/flightaware/tclx):

```
% package require Tclx
8.6
% for_recursive_glob file directory/ {*.txt} { puts $file }
directory/subdirectory1/file.txt
```

With [tcllib](https://www.tcl.tk/software/tcllib/)'s [`fileutil::traverse` package](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/traverse.md):

```
% package require fileutil::traverse
0.6
% proc is_text_file {filename} { string match {*.txt} $filename }
% ::fileutil::traverse iter directory -filter is_text_file
::iter
% iter foreach file { puts $file }
directory/subdirectory1/file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use glob recursively. In the following sample code, $init_dir is the initial directory to search, and $::target is the file name you are looking for.

```
proc recur_glob { init_dir } {
  set list1 [glob -nocomplain ${init_dir}/*]
  foreach s1 $list1 {
    if { [file isdirectory $s1] } {
      recur_glob $s1
    } elseif { [string equal [file tail $s1] $::target] } {
      puts $s1
    }
  }
}

recur_glob $init_dir
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this but didn't know about -nocomplain.

Comment: Without -nocomplain option, glob is aborted if the directory is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the depth that the file is at, you can find the file easily by putting `*` for directories in the path:

```
# Always use -nocomplain with glob
glob -nocomplain */*/file.txt
# ==> directory/subdirectory1/file.txt
```

This only works if you know the depth to find the file at; fully recursive searching isn't implemented in `glob` itself. (The other answers show how to script it.)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! A simple command. Thank you!